# Difference between foreachasync and for loop with entity records?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm curious to know what the difference is between the two statements below and why the .ForEacHAsync doesn't work for creating new rows but the for loop does?

this works and adds new record products

```
var recordProducts = context.RecordsProducts
            .Where(i => i.RecordId == model.OldRecordId);

foreach (var rp in recordProducts)
{
    var newRecordProduct = new RecordProduct
    {
        IsActive = true,
        RecordId = model.RecordId,
        ProductId = rp.ProductId,
        DefendantId = rp.DefendantId,
        Annotation = rp.Annotation
    };
    context.RecordsProducts.Add(newRecordProduct);
}
```

this doesn't

```
var recordProducts = context.RecordsProducts
    .Where(i => i.RecordId == model.OldRecordId)
    .ForEachAsync(a =>
    {
        var newRecordProduct = new RecordProduct
        {
            IsActive = true,
            RecordId = model.RecordId,
            ProductId = a.ProductId,
            DefendantId = a.DefendantId,
            Annotation = a.Annotation
        };
        context.RecordsProducts.Add(newRecordProduct);
    }
);
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is a very poor problem description. What _exactly_ happens that you did not expect? Any compiler error, exception, wrong results?

Comment: no, just that the rows don't get created in the db.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first example, the use of `foreach` with your `IQueryable<RecordProduct> recordProducts` will cause synchronous (*not asynchronous*) lazy-evaluation of the query, so it will block the thread inside the (hidden) call to `IQueryable.GetEnumerator() ...MoveNext()` that happens when you use `foreach`.

...which is equivalent to this:

```
IQueryable<RecordProduct> query = context.RecordsProducts
    .Where(i => i.RecordId == model.OldRecordId);

IEnumerable<RecordProduct> asEnumerable = query;
using( IEnumerator<RecordProduct> iter in asEnumerable.GetEnumerator() )
{
    while( iter.MoveNext() )
    {
        RecordProduct rp = iter.Current;

        DoForEachBodyHere( rp );
    }
}
```

Whereas in the second example, [the `QueryableExtensions.ForEachAsync` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.foreachasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) will load the data asynchronously and run the anonymous function for-each-item as it's loaded and is roughly equivalent to this (or rather: this is how your program is *intended to* work):

```
IQueryable<RecordProduct> query = context.RecordsProducts
    .Where(i => i.RecordId == model.OldRecordId);

using( DataReader rdr = await ExecuteQueryAsDataReaderAsync( query ) )
{
    while( await rdr.ReadAsync() )
    {
        RecordProduct rp = context.ObjectContext.Etc.TranslateIntoEntity( rdr );
        await DoForEachAsyncBodyHere( rp );
    }
}
```

But your second example doesn't work because the the result of your expression is a `Task` which is never `await`ed. If you want to use `ForEachAsync` you need to change your code to this:

```
Task loadTask = context.RecordsProducts
    .Where(i => i.RecordId == model.OldRecordId)
    .ForEachAsync(a =>
    {
        RecordProduct newRecordProduct = new RecordProduct
        {
            IsActive = true,
            RecordId = model.RecordId,
            ProductId = a.ProductId,
            DefendantId = a.DefendantId,
            Annotation = a.Annotation
        };
        context.RecordsProducts.Add(newRecordProduct);
    }
);

await loadTask; // This will wait (actually, _yield_) until all of the `ForEachAsync` iterations are complete.

await context.SaveChangesAsync(); // This will actually save the new rows added to `context.RecordsProducts`
```

...but your program, *as-is*, does not actually do anything useful: when you use EF to load entities via `IQueryable<T>` (without applying any `.Select()` projections) then those loaded entities will be automatically added to their corresponding `DbSet<T>` collections for you; but you don't get duplicates because `DbSet<T>` also prevents duplicate objects being added (remember that [*a set* does not contain duplicates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223405/can-elements-in-a-set-be-duplicated)).

However, assuming you did have some *useful* action to perform for each loaded item, then the "best" approach would be to use EF idiomatically by loading the data asynchronously at-once using EF's built-in `ToListAsync` and then use a normal synchronous `foreach` to do your useful work. As this is IO-bound there's nothing to gain from using concurrency here.

Don't forget to use `await context.SaveChangesAsync()` to save your changes back.

```
List<RecordProduct> list = await context.RecordsProducts
    .Where(i => i.RecordId == model.OldRecordId)
    .ToListAsync();

foreach( RecordProduct rp in list )
{
    // There is no need to manually add `rp` items to `context.RecordsProduct` because EF does that for you already.

    DoSomethingWith( rp );
}

await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: If I don't use the await in the first part, then it returns a Task<List<recordProducts>>, what's the difference between a Task<...> and a List<...> when doing this?

Comment: @user1186050 A `Task<T>` in .NET is equivalent to a `Promise<T>` in JavaScript and `future<T>` in C++. It's not feasible to explain promises in a StackOverflow comment reply. I recommend reading this article instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises